# How to force immediate instantiation of enum values?

Tags: kotlin, enums, jvm, singleton, static-initialization

How to force immediate instantiation of enum values?

By default, in Kotlin enums are instantiated on first access (like `object`s/singletons), i.e., the following minimal example

```kotlin
class Foo

fun create(msg: String) = Foo().also { println("$msg") }

enum class A(val foo: Foo) {
    ONE(create("1")),
    TWO(create("2"))
}

enum class B(val foo: Foo) {
    THREE(create("3")),
    FOUR(create("4"))
}

fun main() {
    println("main")
    println(A.ONE)
}
```

outputs:

```
main
1
2
ONE
```

Is it possible to force the enums to be instantiated directly/statically before `main`, such that the output is as follows?

```
1
2
3
4
main
ONE
```

Sure, I could just put something like `val ignore = listOf(A.ONE, B.THREE)` somewhere, but I'd like to avoid such manual repetition.

Maybe there's a way using some existing annotation, or creating a new one, or something else? :)

Answer (score 1):

JVM loads classes only on first access. This is not only for kotlin but also for Java. For Java we have ways to initialize a class before main, for instance, static initializer block, or `Class.forName`. Similarly you can use the static initializer block in Kotlin.

```
object Temp {
    init {
        A.ONE
    }

    @JvmStatic fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        println("main")
        println(A.ONE)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'd like to avoid such manual repetition like in the `init` block because it's easy to forget one of the enums there. I've edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Use a library (e.g. Reflections) to scan your application, extract all enums, and load them before you start your logic.

Comment: Or just rethink your software design. Relying on side effects applied in class initialization simply is the wrong way to go.

Comment: @Holger Yes, I'm already doing it differently in the actual application. But now I was curious. :)